# Can one Mac boot up to several OS X installation?

Tags: dual-boot, multi-boot

Since there will be iOS 6 / Xcode 4.5 Beta or Preview and Mountain Lion Beta or Preview, I wonder if using an iMac with 1TB of hard drive, can it be partitioned using its Disk Utility into 4 or 5 partitions, and install Lion on each of those partitions except one partition for Mountain Lion Beta?

Or alternatively, if it is a Mac Mini with 500GB and it is partitioned into 3 partitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely have any number of OS X installs on any number of partitions. Use the Startup Disk preference pane or hold down <kbd>Option</kbd> at boot to choose which partition to boot.

Comment: if I buy a new iMac with Lion, the Lion won't have an installation DVD?  So I have to actually buy Lion again in the App Store for $29.99 to install on the other partitions, I think?

Comment: Macs that come with Lion have an install partition on the hard drive instead of a DVD. Apple has instructions on their support site to copy the partition to a flash drive so you have it if the hard drive goes down.